# improve delay detection between two signals

Tags: correlation

Hi there I'm trying to measure time delay of one percussive event recorded by two contact mikes on a glass surface. I decided to check the cross correlation (via FFT) and detect the index of the max in the function. The method is really jittery as the medium affects the transfer function of the signal. I wonder if there is a better method than cross correlation or some signal cleaning that can help before the calculation, or in the cross-correlation function. Also there might be a way to reconstruct the distortion transfer through the medium (as in phase cancellation)..any help?

Comment: Perhaps a simple high-pass filter before the cross-correlation can help.

Comment: thanks for the answer but I tried different filters and they remove some noise but still don't fix the correlation issue. Some papers suggest using the GCC generalized correlation.